# Find the maximal upscaled dimension while respecting a ratio

Tags: php, math, resize

Me and a college are trying to build a method that can find the biggest size for a selection displayed by default in an image. The selection is having a ratio.

Until now, we've tried this:

```
public function findBestSizeForRatio($inputW, $inputH, $ratioW, $ratioH)
{
    if($inputW / $ratioW > $ratioH / $inputH){
        $w = floor($inputW / $ratioW) * $ratioW;
        $h = $w * $ratioH / $ratioW;
    }
    else{
        $h = floor($inputH / $ratioH) * $ratioH;
        $w = $h * $ratioW / $ratioH;
    }

    return array($w, $h);
}
```

But it fail our unit tests.

We've also tried this:

```
public function findBestSizeForRatio($inputW, $inputH, $ratioW, $ratioH)
{
     return $this->findBestSizeInBox($ratioW*10000, $ratioH*10000, $inputW, $inputH);
}
public function findBestSizeInBox($inputW, $inputH, $boxW, $boxH)
{
    if($inputW / $boxW > $inputH / $boxH){
        return array($boxW, round($inputH * $boxW / $inputW));
    }
    else{
        return array(round($inputW * $boxH / $inputH), $boxH);
    }
}
```

It seem to work, but it's not pixel perfect. As our ratio is made of small number, we need a method that REALLY respect the ratio, even if the image is not 100% filled. And it's also really dumb to hardcode constant like *10000 because we're unable to figure out a good math formula. ;)

We've also build those PHPUnit tests, that seemed like representative to us ( So we might have forgot some cases)

```
/**
 * @covers Img_GD::findBestSizeInBox
 */
public function testfindBestSizeForRatioReturnValidValueForEasyInput()
{

    $img = new Img_GD();

    //1
    $iW = 400; $iH = 300; //Input image size
    $rW =   4; $rH =   3; //ratio
    $eW = 400; $eH = 300; //Expected
    $this->assertEquals(array($eW, $eH), $img->findBestSizeForRatio($iW, $iH, $rW, $rH), "Img: {$iW} x {$iH} Ratio: {$rW} x {$rH}");

    //2
    $iW = 400; $iH = 3000; //Input image size
    $rW =   4; $rH =   3; //ratio
    $eW = 400; $eH = 300; //Expected
    $this->assertEquals(array($eW, $eH), $img->findBestSizeForRatio($iW, $iH, $rW, $rH), "Img: {$iW} x {$iH} Ratio: {$rW} x {$rH}");

    //3
    $iW = 4000; $iH = 300; //Input image size
    $rW =   4; $rH =   3; //ratio.
    $eW = 400; $eH = 300; //Expected
    $this->assertEquals(array($eW, $eH), $img->findBestSizeForRatio($iW, $iH, $rW, $rH), "Img: {$iW} x {$iH} Ratio: {$rW} x {$rH}");

    //4
    $iW = 400; $iH = 3000; //Input image size
    $rW =   3; $rH =   4; //ratio
    $eW = 399; $eH = 532; //Expected
    $this->assertEquals(array($eW, $eH), $img->findBestSizeForRatio($iW, $iH, $rW, $rH), "Img: {$iW} x {$iH} Ratio: {$rW} x {$rH}");

    //5
    $iW = 4000; $iH = 300; //Input image size
    $rW =   3; $rH =   4; //ratio.
    $eW = 225; $eH = 300; //Expected
    $this->assertEquals(array($eW, $eH), $img->findBestSizeForRatio($iW, $iH, $rW, $rH), "Img: {$iW} x {$iH} Ratio: {$rW} x {$rH}");

    //6
    $iW = 4000; $iH = 300; //Input image size
    $rW =   3; $rH =   4; //ratio.
    $eW = 225; $eH = 300; //Expected
    $this->assertEquals(array($eW, $eH), $img->findBestSizeForRatio($iW, $iH, $rW, $rH), "Img: {$iW} x {$iH} Ratio: {$rW} x {$rH}");

}

/**
 * @covers Img_GD::findBestSizeInBox
 */
public function testfindBestSizeForRatioReturnValidValueForNonExactInput()
{
    $img = new Img_GD();

    //7
    $iW = 403; $iH = 302; //Input image size
    $rW =   4; $rH =   3; //ratio
    $eW = 400; $eH = 300; //Expected
    $this->assertEquals(array($eW, $eH), $img->findBestSizeForRatio($iW, $iH, $rW, $rH), "Img: {$iW} x {$iH} Ratio: {$rW} x {$rH}");

    //8
    $iW = 403; $iH = 3000; //Input image size
    $rW =   4; $rH =   3; //ratio
    $eW = 400; $eH = 300; //Expected
    $this->assertEquals(array($eW, $eH), $img->findBestSizeForRatio($iW, $iH, $rW, $rH), "Img: {$iW} x {$iH} Ratio: {$rW} x {$rH}");

    //9
    $iW = 4000; $iH = 302; //Input image size
    $rW =   4; $rH =   3; //ratio.
    $eW = 400; $eH = 300; //Expected
    $this->assertEquals(array($eW, $eH), $img->findBestSizeForRatio($iW, $iH, $rW, $rH), "Img: {$iW} x {$iH} Ratio: {$rW} x {$rH}");

    //10
    $iW = 403; $iH = 3000; //Input image size
    $rW =   3; $rH =   4; //ratio
    $eW = 402; $eH = 536; //Expected
    $this->assertEquals(array($eW, $eH), $img->findBestSizeForRatio($iW, $iH, $rW, $rH), "Img: {$iW} x {$iH} Ratio: {$rW} x {$rH}");

    //11
    $iW = 4000; $iH = 302; //Input image size
    $rW =   3; $rH =   4; //ratio.
    $eW = 225; $eH = 300; //Expected
    $this->assertEquals(array($eW, $eH), $img->findBestSizeForRatio($iW, $iH, $rW, $rH), "Img: {$iW} x {$iH} Ratio: {$rW} x {$rH}");

    //12
    $iW = 4000; $iH = 302; //Input image size
    $rW =   3; $rH =   4; //ratio.
    $eW = 225; $eH = 300; //Expected
    $this->assertEquals(array($eW, $eH), $img->findBestSizeForRatio($iW, $iH, $rW, $rH), "Img: {$iW} x {$iH} Ratio: {$rW} x {$rH}");

}
```

Any solution that would passes all the tests?

Comment: If it's the precision of your calculations that concerns you, you might want to check out http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php or http://php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php

Comment: @Mikk it's not that I need precision like floating point precision. It's that I don't want rounding. If Look at the test #4. I don't want 400 x 533.333 , I'll want 399 x 532, as it's impossible to maintain the ratio with an ideal width of 400. I only want integer in my results, always, and not rounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one subtle change:

```
public function findBestSizeForRatio($inputW, $inputH, $ratioW, $ratioH)
{
    if($inputW / $ratioW < $inputH / $ratioH){
        $w = floor($inputW / $ratioW) * $ratioW;
        $h = $w * $ratioH / $ratioW;
    }
    else{
        $h = floor($inputH / $ratioH) * $ratioH;
        $w = $h * $ratioW / $ratioH;
    }

    return array($w, $h);
}
```

I see you already fixed your unit tests as [btilly suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5971101/php-find-the-maximal-upscaled-dimension-while-respecting-a-ratio/5971584#5971584); good.

Answer (score 2):

Let me be sure that I have this right.  You want to take an image, and take the biggest chunk that you can which is a rectangle with exactly the specified h/w ratio.

In that case remember the rule that unit tests are code as well.  When you fail your unit test, there are even odds that the mistake is in the unit test.  With that in mind, your unit tests look wrong.  For instance take #4.  533/400 is not in an exact 4/3 ratio.  The best possible answer with that exact ratio is 532/399.

If you're willing to relax the exactness of the ratio, then you should do something like:

```
public function findBestSizeForRatio($inputW, $inputH, $ratioW, $ratioH)
{
    if($inputW / $ratioW > $ratioH / $inputH){
        $w = $inputW;
        $h = round($w * $ratioH / $ratioW);
    }
    else{
        $h = $inputH;
        $h = round($h * $ratioW / $ratioH);
    }

    return array($w, $h);
}
```

Comment: You've understood the problem correctly. But no, I don't want to relax. As you've notice, I already have that method (and it's working well). And you're right, the test #4 was wrong, as you pointed out, the expected result should be 532/399. I'll edit the post.

Comment: @FMaz008: Ah.  In that case something along the lines of `$w = $inputW - ($inputW % $ratioW)` and then `$h = $w * $ratioH / $ratioW`.  This assumes that `$ratioW` and `$ratioH` are relatively prime.  If you can't assume that, it is easy to guarantee it by dividing them by the gcd.  Search for "gcd" in http://php.net/manual/en/ref.math.php to find a sample implementation of that.

Comment: @btilly Isn't $w = $inputW - ($inputW % $ratioW) and $w = floor($inputW / $ratioW) * $ratioW; return pretty much the same ? I don't see much differences... And yes, I do assume that the ratio will reduced ( 40/30 will always be 4/3 )

Comment: @FMaz008: Yes, they should be the same.  Hrm.  Could you be failing your unit test due to roundoff errors causing floating point numbers to not match?  Try `$base = floor($inputW / $ratioW); $w = $base * $ratioW; $h = $base * $ratioH;` and see if that works.  If not, take another look at your unit test.

Comment: @btilly As far as I've been able to understand, the problem is my IF condition. I've some test that pass. If I reverse the equality, I'll have other test that will pass. And in both case, each time I get a test that fail, I would have the good values with the formula in the other IF case... My opinion (and I might be wrong) is that my IF condition miss a detail. I don't think about something.

Comment: @FMaz008 - D'oh!  `$inputW / $ratioW > $ratioH / $inputH` should be `$inputW / $ratioW > $inputH / $ratioH`.